# What happens to the nitrogen when an oxygen machine delivers only oxygen?

Tags: biochemistry

My father recently began using an oxygen machine. He would like to know where the nitrogen goes when the machine takes in air and puts out only oxygen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because are OP doesn't show attempt at an answer.

Comment: Did you try finding an answer? *' Provide details. Share your research. '*

Answer (score 2):

The nitrogen is returned to the air around the machine.  See [Wikipedia's article on the oxygen concentrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_concentrator) for details about how the machine separates the nitrogen and oxygen.